# Missing CSS file and images after URL rewrite

Tags: php, css, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make user friendly URL using mode rewrite.
My problem is, that after giving category like 'name' to my URL, when I call the page using new URL, it can't load the CSS file or images.

I have a link like:

> localhost/mywebsite/project?id=22

New link is something like

> localhost/mywebsite/project/22/myproject.project

htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]*)/.*\.project$ /project.php?project=$1 [L]
```

(it might not be 100% right but I don't have access to my code right now so I just wrote this and it works fine on the original source)

My root directory is localhost/mywebsite/

and my CSS file is in css/style.css

> localhost/mywebsite/css/style.css

my htaccess

> localhost/mywebsite/.htaccess

and my project.php file is in

> localhost/mywebsite/project.php

So in the project page I have access to CSS file by using relative path,

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but when I use rewritten URL page can't find the CSS file.

I can't use absolute path with domain name because I don't have domain yet! and it can be anything.

one way is to use relative path to domain as suggested on the similar questions
localhost/mywebsite/project.php
and when i run my script localy my root directory is 
localhost 
so css link should look like

> href="mywebsite/css/style.css"

but when i go live i should change all links to probably something like

> href="/css/style.css"

this seems like lots of work

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For your local version add

```
<base href="//localhost/mywebsite" />
```

to the head section

and for your live versions change it to

```
<base href="//your.domain.here" />
```

reference at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4

Comment: yeah but also there are images and i cant change domain name for every single image after going live

Comment: @max, `base` tag works with images as well.. example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/JE656/

Answer (score 2):

you have to define the base path or the server view path in the connection.php and whenever u want that path, make that global. then that variable will b called and the css or images will take the whole path.

for example
$SVP="http://www.example.com/"

global $SVP;
echo $SVP;

so

Answer (score 1):

Insert an image into the same file with the same relative path as the css href link, load the page in a browser, right-click the image in internet explorer, click properties and you should see where the relative path actually points to.

Comment: apparently i should include mywebsite  on he link cuz localhost considered to be my root and /mywebsite/ folder is just another directory so it should be included in the link . i cant change all off the links when i'm going live !

Comment: You cant change all the links understandable hassle so keep all paths relative but adjust each path with the correct relative location. Note: i didnt mean use the absolute path i meant check the absolute path and adjust your relative path until you get it right. You can use ../ to go up a folder.