# Rewrite URL .htaccess, mod_rewrite - "directory not found"

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm rewriting urls so my member pages - domain.com/profile.php?id=123 becomes domain.com/user/John

If somebody try to reach domain.com/user, the web browser says directory not found. Is there a way to make this directory "real", without adding the folder and an index file? In the .htaccess file?

When I call some scripts firebug will warn me about that the directory doesn't exists as well.

Here's the rewrite rule and entire .htaccess-file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

RewriteRule ^user/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Post your rewrite rules please. If you are getting 404s, you probably have faulty rewrites.

Comment: You're getting 404 on user/ "folder" because you have no rules that apply to it without a username after it...

Comment: So how do I fix it? (I know very little about htaccess..)

Comment: What should be rendered if `user/` is submitted without a username following it?

Comment: Doesn't matter really. Back to root I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > "What should be rendered if user/ is submitted without a username following it?"
>
> Doesn't matter really. Back to root I guess.

Then write a rule specifically for that:

```
RewriteRule ^user/?$ / [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem with the 404, however now, at domain.com/user the page gets broken script links: domain.com/user/javascript/file.js etc.. Is it possible to send it back to root and remove "/user" from location?

Comment: @user1121487 This is a relative URL issue, use the `<base>` tag in your header to fix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8216451/851273

Answer (score 2):

Are you placing `http://` before "domain.com" in your URL?

Your server will attempt to look for a file path if you do not specify the protocol.

Comment: I've updated my post with my .htaccess file. It doesn't matter either way with the http://...

Answer (score 0):

It's been one year sonce your post, still you have saved me, for three days I've been searching for a solution as to why it won't read my slash instead it could read any other character
You're getting 404 on user/ "folder" because you have no rules that apply to it without a username after it... – poncha Jun 24 '12 at 18:41
Thank you Poncha and Jon Lin