# IIS 7 no images when friendly url is on

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, friendly-url, url-rewrite-module

I am using two simple rules to realize friendly url.

They are working find but I cannot see images and there is an ***error***

**Friednly URL of ASP.NET 3.5 Website**

```
http://localhost/Test/Products/888/9999
```

**Error**

> http://localhost/Test/Products/888/Images/Jellyfish.jpg Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

**Rules**

```
  <rule name="t2" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^products/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)" negate="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="products.aspx?p={R:1}&amp;pc={R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="t1" enabled="true">
                    <match url="^product/([0-9]+)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="product.aspx?p={R:1}" />
                </rule>
```

I see that IIS is building wrong path to images like it says

> http://localhost/Test/Products/888/Images/Jellyfish.jpg

Any clue?

Comment: I don't fully understand. Do you except the url `http://localhost/Test/Products/888/9999` to return the image at location `http://localhost/Test/Products/888/Images/Jellyfish.jpg`, or does your product.aspx returns an image. Whats the real url of the image you want to get?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf The Url `http://localhost/Test/Products/888/9999` is to open Products.aspx. But somehow IIS is rewriting paths to images inside of this page. This page has a simple `  <img src="Images/Jellyfish.jpg" />` that is working just fine  without rewriting rules.

Comment: so the src of the image is relative to the page, the browser will request something like `http://localhost/Test/Products/888/9999/images/jellyfish.jpg', that is picked up by your rewrite rules. In the F12 browser tools, check the actual requested url for the image. You have to to exclude the images from your rule or use a non-relative path.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf How I can do this?

Comment: You could add a condition like `<conditions><add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.jpg" negate="true" /></conditions>` to your rules or maybe `<conditions><add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /></conditions>` You have to make sure your images are not matching the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer here [Missing CSS file and images after URL rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216306/missing-css-file-and-images-after-url-rewrite)

We have to use in MasterPage's header this line

```
<base href="//your.domain.here" />
```

You can read about it here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp