# Rewrite URL with NGINX

Tags: php, regex, nginx, url-rewriting, server

I have a blog coded with php with several articles, but to read a post the url should be like `http://myblog/post.php?url=an-article-tilte&id=7`.

I want to make a smartest way to access articles with their url (and to improve the referencing). In my database, each article has an `url` attribute that contains its title in '[kebab-case](https://lodash.com/docs#kebabCase)' (eg. 'Welcome to my blog' will be 'welcome-to-my-blog').

To sum up, to access the 'Welcome to my blog' post (with id equal to 7) I would type `http://myblog.com/post/welcome-to-my-blog-7` and not `http://myblog.com/post.php?url=welcome-to-my-blog&id=7` .

In my blog nginx configuration file I have this :

```
server {
    listen   80;
    root /opt/http/nginx/sites/myblog/www;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name myblog.com www.myblog.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    client_max_body_size 3M;

    error_page 403 /index.php;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css;
    gzip_vary on;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/www.myblog.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/www.myblog.error.log;
}
```

And I guess I have to put inside something like this, but it makes an error when I try to restart nginx. So I don't know what's wrong in it.

```
location @rewrites {
    if ($uri ~* ^/post/([a-zA-Z0-0\-]+)-([0-9]+)) {
        rewrite ^/post.php?url=$1&id=$2;
    }
}
```

With apache it was easy, but is there a way to reproduce it on nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the missing dollar `$` to close the regex string, you can anyhow rewrite your rule as following:

```
location /post/ {
    rewrite ^/post/([\w-]+)-(\d+)$ /post.php?url=$1&id=$2;
}
```

Where:

- `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (if you prefer remove unescore `_` rewrite it in the extended version)
- `\d` is `[0-9]`

*NOTE*: if you use `~*` it's a case insensitive match (the double `A-Za-z` is not needed).

**UPDATE**: if i understand correctly what do you need, we have to rewrite the rule to do the opposite (make a request to `post.php?url={kebab-title}&id={id-number}` and actually obtain the url of ``post/{kebab-title}-{id-number}

```
location ~ ^/post\.php\?url=(.*)&id=(\d*)$ {
    alias /post/$1-$2;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
to avoid unwanted matches under `/post/` you can also use this alternative (more specific) version:

```
location ~ ^/post/((?:\w+-)+\w+)-(\d+)$ {
    rewrite /post.php?url=$1&id=$2;
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it's exactly the idea i'm was looking for! And now, i've got a 404 on the link `http://myblog.com/post/an-example-article-8`. But i'm sure we gonna solve this!

Comment: @MaximeLafarie: try the solution proposed in the update, i think is what you need.

Comment: I'm so sorry, your first answer is working like a charm! What I forgot is that my blog is in a 'blog' directory, and then I had to adapt your answer with adding '/blog' before all '/' in the code. I done it everywhere but I forgot to do it here : `/post.php?url=$1&id=$2;`. Thank you for your answer, it's exactly what I was looking for and thanks to you I now understand how nginx url rewriting works.

Comment: a [little trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216306/missing-css-file-and-images-after-url-rewrite) to avoid 404 errors, and all works fine! Thank you! Happy coding too!

Comment: @MaximeLafarie: if you want to try another approach (less obscure in the long run), i think the last refined update have to works avoid unwanted matches.