# Rewrite get parameters url with nginx and redirect

Tags: php, nginx

I've been trying for a hours without figure it out.. if someone can help me..

I have a url like this:
`example.com/test.php?action=value1&step=value2`

I want to rewrite a url to:
`example.com/test/value1/value2`

I have tried:
`rewrite ^/?test/(.*?)/?$ /test.php?action=$1 last;`

however i need to url to **redirect** too for the new url, also i don't know how to rewrite with multiple params/values..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewrite URL with NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570847/rewrite-url-with-nginx)

Comment: Not really, they asnwer is for other type of redirect.. didn't work for me.

Comment: @AmirMB his answer do exactly what iv'e tried, but i need to redirect too..